Get cell Index/ID by cell value via VBA Function
i have a excel sheet that regularly updated. Thus, for certain values i wanted to use/refer, the cell ID or index is not fixed, but certain nearby other/intermediate (like section title, name, school, gender) inputs (can be number or text) are fixed. Therefore, i have to find the nearby intermediate cell ID by using cell values/input, then down or right few cells (let us say one cell) to get my target cell value/index. Then i can use the target cell id/index/address for other purpose. i followed this to create my own function. The whole worksheet (sheet1) is used for search and find.
Function FindCellIndex(SearchString)
    
    Dim SearchRange As Range, cl As Range
    Dim FirstFound As String

    Application.FindFormat.Clear

        Set cl = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:=SearchString, _
            After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not cl Is Nothing Then        
            FirstFound = cl.Address
        End If

FindCellIndex  = cl.Address

End Function

Checking the function
Sub Search()
 
 myid=FindCellIndex("David")
 MsgBox myid

End Sub

When i run the above code, the message box showing nothing. It seems it is empty.
I am trying to extract cell ID/addresss by cell values, but the function i wrote is not working properly.

The function does not return anything.  It highlights every where the values is found, not sure what you are intending to return.

Nothing from FindCellIndex outputs, e.g., function tbd(rng as range) // tbd = rng.offset(1).value would output the next cell's value.  You need something similar.

I believe you want FindCellIndex  = cl.Address just before you end your function, and that would resolve your issue.

@ScottCraner If the "David" is in cell "A5", i want to return the "A5" index of the cell by using cell value of "David".

@Cyril That was the ultimate goal. but the above function is to get the Cell ID  by Cell inputs/values (like name David cell) first.

The function you are using loops, it is assuming that there are many Davids in the data.  If you only want to return the first find Get rid of the DO loop and just do what @Cyril stated

@ScottCraner, i tried as you said, but it stil showing nothing. the message box is still empty.

@Cyril, updated the code as above per your suggestions, but it is still not working.
